# MessageBox() returning 0 when called from Win32 button press

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, messagebox, win32gui

I'm barely a week into Win32 GUI programming, so I'm confident/hopeful this is something simple. For your consideration, I've provided a sample of my code below.

As a quick brief, my application watches for another application to be open so that I can modify that application's memory. I've placed this initial check at the top of my UI looper as follows such that it will only run once (in which case the user can only cancel and the app closes, or execution resumes past the `if` statement with hWndApp having a value assigned):

```
if (!hWndApp) {
    appCheck();
}
```

If I start my application and the other application isn't running, `appCheck();` fires and the waterfall of execution therefrom acts accordingly: a message box appears (and will keep appearing if the user clicks "Retry") until the other application's window is found. If the user clicks "Cancel," the application exits and all is well. If they click "Retry" once the other application is running, then my application will finish painting to the screen and execution is normal.

The funny business starts the next time I call `appCheck();` (which happens when one of either two buttons is clicked) *if the other application has been opened, then closed*.

While debugging (via Visual Studio 2017), the variable I assign the `MessageBox()` call to equals 0 when the other application has been opened, then closed, then the following:

1. Push button to call `appCheck();`
2. `getProcessHandleAndPID();` is then called within the `if` statement because the window can't be found
3. `AppCheckMessageBox();` is then called within the `while` loop because the window can't be found
4. The debugger then points to the first line inside of `AppCheckMessageBox();`, which is the entire `int msgboxID = MessageBox();` bit
5. Pressing F11 (Step Into), no window shows and the application exists after the `default` choice in the switch statement is triggered since the value of `msgboxID` is 0 (indicating the `MessageBox()` call failed, so I tried calling `GetLastError()` before `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`, but to no avail).

I'm not sure where my error lies, but I've sought many solutions--none of which have panned out. Finally, if you see any variables below that look misnamed or undeclared, it's solely due to my modification of the code for this post to try to generalize/ shorten it. I may have left out some global variable declarations, etc.

Thank you for any help/guidance you can provide! I'm at my wit's end with this right now...lol.

```
//--------------------------------------------------
// Function to get process handle and PID of app  /
//------------------------------------------------
void getProcessHandleAndPID()
{
    hWndApp = FindWindow(NULL, _T("NameOfApplication"));

    while (!hWndApp) {
        AppCheckMessageBox();
    }
    //Much more code here
}

//---------------------------------
// Function to show message box  /
//-------------------------------
int AppCheckMessageBox()
{
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL, //I tried making this hWndApp as well, but no difference
        (LPCWSTR)L"Cancel to exit or start the app and click Retry.",
        (LPCWSTR)L"Application Not Found!",
        MB_ICONSTOP | MB_RETRYCANCEL | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_SETFOREGROUND
    );

    switch (msgboxID)
    {
    case IDCANCEL:
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case IDRETRY:
        getProcessHandleAndPID();
        break;
    default:
        //GetLastError();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return msgboxID;
}

//------------------------------------------------
// Function to check if application is running  /
//----------------------------------------------
void appCheck() {
    if (!FindWindow(NULL, _T("NameOfApplication"))) {
        getProcessHandleAndPID();
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------
// Function to get process handle and PID of app  /
//------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (!hWndApp) {
        appCheck();
    }

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        //Code here
        break;

    case WM_CREATE:
        //Code here
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (HIWORD(wParam))
        {
            case BN_CLICKED:
                if (LOWORD(wParam) == BTN_ENABLE) {
                    appCheck();
                //Do stuff with button press
            }
                if (LOWORD(wParam) == BTN_DISABLE) {
                    appCheck();
                //Do stuff with button press
            }
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: WndProc is called for every single message delivered to your window. Each time that happens you show a dialog which will lead to more messages. Hence the endless message box dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, David. So bearing that in mind, do you have a recommendation for how or where else I should tie that button functionality such that it doesn't cause the error? Do I need to specify something prior to calling appCheck(); with a button click, or can/should I wrap that call in something? I'm really scratching my head with how best to tie certain logic in relation to the UI looper in Win32. As an aside, I'm starting to work my way through this, so it may serve to demystify a lot of this for me: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I've really no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You may well know of a better way to go about this. My overall goal is to have my application always check for if a certain other application is running. If it's not, then let the user know. Originally, I though I would create a thread that monitors and then updates a label in the UI accordingly. I couldn't get that working correctly, so I moved to the idea of using a message box to inform the user. I currently have that check tied once on app launch, and each time the user clicks a button. It's when they click the button and the app isn't found that my problem occurs.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use polling at all. I'd listen for new processes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig into that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but too long for comments:

1. This isn't your real code. Many things are missing, there are mismatched braces which would prevent compilation, etc. Always show your real code if you want help.
2. As David says, calling `appCheck()` every time you receive a message is the wrong approach. If you want to call it once after your window opens, do that before entering your message loop.
3. Your code is needlessly recursive (`getProcessHandleAndPID()` calls `AppCheckMessageBox()` which calls `getProcessHandleAndPID()` which calls...) and will potentially lead to a stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

1. Fixed the brace issue in the example. As noted in the post, I took the relevant snippet from my code which is hundreds of lines, thus why I didn't paste it all. Compilation isn't the issue.

2. This, I think, hits on the problem. My overall goal is to always check for if a certain other app is running, then let the user know accordingly. I wanted this to be a thread that updates a label in the UI, but I couldn't pin this down.

3. This is intentional behavior to keep showing the Retry/Cancel window if the user clicks "Retry" and the other app still isn't found.

Comment: You can trivially refactor to achieve that outcome without the recursion.